# Do internal SATA drives support S.M.A.R.T.?

Tags: sata

I am only wondering for raw internal SATA drives, not SATA drives in other enclosures and bridges such as USB, FireWire, etc.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, they do.

Diagnostic tools such as SpeedFan, or vendor tools from Intel and Western Digital read/test it.